# how to toggle display for only a particular thumbnail

Tags: javascript, java, android, angularjs, ionic-framework

we have developed an app that displays all the videos in our channel.we first display thumbnails, then we click on the thumbnail,we want only the related video of that thumbnail,not all the videos

Angular Code

```
 $scope.isvideoPlaying = false;
$scope.displayvideo = function(){
   $scope.isvideoPlaying = true;
}
```

html code

```
<div class="list card" ng-repeat="video in videos | filter:searchBox" >
          <div class="item item-text-wrap">
            <h2>{{video.snippet.title}}</h2>
            <p><i class="ion ion-ios-calendar-outline"></i> {{video.snippet.publishedAt }}</p>
          </div>
          <div class="item item-image">
            <img ng-src="{{video.snippet.thumbnails.high.url}}" ng-show="!isvideoPlaying" ng-click="displayvideo()"> 
            <!-- Use 'youtube-video' as an element or attribute. -->
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" ng-show="isvideoPlaying">
              <youtube-video class="embed-responsive-item" video-id="video.id.videoId" player-vars="playerVars"></youtube-video>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this, (I am assuming 'video.id.videoId' is your video object ID)

```
 $scope.isvideoPlaying = {}
 $scope.displayvideo = function(id){
   $scope.isvideoPlaying[id] = true;
 }
```

And HTML,

```
<div class="list card" ng-repeat="video in videos | filter:searchBox" >
      <div class="item item-text-wrap">
        <h2>{{video.snippet.title}}</h2>
        <p><i class="ion ion-ios-calendar-outline"></i> {{video.snippet.publishedAt }}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item item-image">
        <img ng-src="{{video.snippet.thumbnails.high.url}}" ng-show="!isvideoPlaying[video.id.videoId]" ng-click="displayvideo(video.id.videoId)"> 
        <!-- Use 'youtube-video' as an element or attribute. -->
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" ng-show="isvideoPlaying[video.id.videoId]">
          <youtube-video class="embed-responsive-item" video-id="video.id.videoId" player-vars="playerVars"></youtube-video>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: also tell me how to give a function, if searchbox is empty then it have to loadvideos and if anything is entered in a searchbox it have to search that particular video and when remove that in searchbox then should again come back to the starting page..im facing a problem that the page is loading very slow

Comment: already we done that,loading time is getting more.could u tell me how to link searchbox with q parameter in url when anything is typed in searchbox,it have to change the q parameter dynamically                                     
     $scope.searchVideos = function() {
       var params = $scope.youtubeParams; 
       if ($scope.q) {
         params['q'] = $scope.q;
       }
       loadVideos(params, function(searchVideos){
         if (searchVideos) {
           $scope.videos = $scope.videos.concat(searchVideos);
         }

Comment: @jahnavi add ng-change